# Driver source for PL-2303X/H Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am working on iRobot Create project that I recently assigned to and I've got a `PL-2303X/H` serial port to connect the robot with my computer. But, when I tried out basic python script from ROS packages (like turtlebot_node), it returns an error message that says ...

> Make sure the irobot create is connected to the computer

But, I plugged in the port accordingly, give it the permission (`sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0`) and when I read through the web, there is a Linux driver source for `PL-2303X USB-serial adapter`.

http://koti.mbnet.fi/lonnberg/pl2303x.html

But, my kernel is `3.5.0-42-generic` and I couldn't get the patch from the link working in my system. Is there any way to install the driver source for `PL-2303X/H` in Ubuntu 12.04? What can I do to get my PL-2303X/H serial port up-and-running with the iRobot Create?

Any suggestions?